# Twitter bootstrap caret size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a caret like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#mylist"
       style="display:inline-block;padding-left:0px;">
 <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

Is it possible to make this caret bigger with CSS or etc.

Comment: You need to change the size of the borders used in the `.caret` class.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The caret is a css psuedo element and constructed using the borders of a transparent element.  See the answer at - [How is the caret on Twitter Bootstrap constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404923/how-is-the-caret-on-twitter-bootstrap-constructed) which gives a much better explanation and useful links.

To answer your question, you can create a new css class/overwrite `.caret` to increases the borders to your required size.

```
.caret {
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #000000;
}
```

increase the `px` size to get the required size. Keep in mind that the three values should be the same if you want an equilateral triangle.

Comment: +1 for the solution. Keep in mind that even though the three values are the same, the triangle is NOT equilateral ;) cheers

Comment: You are awesome! Just spent 20min trying to figure out font-size was not working because I was assuming it was a type of icon. :)

Comment: If you're compiling your own Less in Bootstrap 3, look for `@caret-width-base` (and `@caret-width-large`) within variables.less. Change those values to increase (or decrease) caret size.

Comment: @Soulriser thanks, that is the correct solution. The other one breaks in certain components (dropup button, for example)

Answer (score 6):

As I can't comment on the accepted answer, I would like to suggest tweaking that solution to use border-width to prevent global color styling of the caret, less code and includes automatic styling of the dropup caret.

```
.caret {
    border-width: 8px;
}
```

In case you need a different shaped caret, you can use left, right, top, bottom:

```
border-left-width: 8px;
border-right-width: 8px;
border-top-width: 10px;
border-bottom-width: 10px;
```

or

```
border-width: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for **Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6** Support, you just have to change the selector to `.dropdown-toggle::after` and override what's coming from "_nav.scss" like so:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: inline-block; /* Default */
    width: 0; /* Default */
    height: 0; /* Default */
    margin-left: .3em; /* Default */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Default */
    content: ""; /* Default */
    border-top: .6em solid; /* caret size */
    border-right: .6em solid transparent; /* caret size */
    border-left: .6em solid transparent; /* caret size */
}
```

Hope this helps those exploring Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style only 'one' caret ( or repetitive one kind) then you can use 'style' attribute to resize the caret. For eg:

```
<span class="caret" style="border-width:8px;"></span>
```

This will not affect other caret elements and only the tag containing this 'border-width' attribute will be affected!

Alternatively, if you want to keep the style in your css file you can label id attribute:

```
<span class="caret" id="c1"></span>
```

And add the styling in your .css as follows:

```
#c1{
    border-width:8px;
}
```